Looking for a site that shows major Japanese train routes and their speed/duration
Inspired by this question. Is there something similar for Japan?
Thinking map of rail links among major cities. Speed and duration optional. Instead may be more helpful to indicate ticket requirements. For example, base fare + limited express or change in rail company.

So something like https://www.jrpass.com/map ?

@JonCuster Thanks, that's a cool map even if it seems to only include JR lines.

As suggestion in wonderbears's answer on the other question, Open Railway Map in "Max Speeds" style is a very good option, and it has (at least some) data for Japan:

